# Ruby Rails, jQuery, Uploadify - weird UTF-8 error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, uploadify

I'm setting up jQuery and Uploadify in my Rails app (with the uploadify-rails plugin). Its all going fine, the flash is loaded, the authenticity paramater is passed through along with the session key and so on. However, my MySQL queries on the way to handling the upload from the flash are all reporting a 'redundant UTF-8 sequence' error. It doesn't matter what the SQL seems to be, just that the first one called gets the error:

```
Processing RoomsController#update to json (for 86.162.102.136 at 2010-04-26 11:27:55) [PUT]
Parameters: {"Filename"=>"fb-logo.png",  "_myapp_session"=>"BAh7CzoPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlY2I5N2FjYjQ4ZjcwMmQzMzQxMjIwMmRmN2EwM2ZhZWM6EWludmFsaWRfdXNlckY6EF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuIjEzSWtvaGJrWDNhQXV6OGtuUllyMmdhbkVnR3JKV2QrM3RrVVJZaTJiak1vPToQam9pbl9zb3VyY2UiN2h0dHA6Ly9iZXRhLmNyYXNocGFkZGVyLmNvbS9wcm9maWxlL2V4Y2VsbGVudGxhcmtzIgpmbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVyOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoewAGOgpAdXNlZHsAOgx1c2VyX2lkaQY=--52b594041395bf8cf5998859eb43c4ed82c74490", "format"=>"json", "folder"=>"/rooms/", "action"=>"update", "authenticity_token"=>"3IkohkX3aAuz8knRYr2ganEgGrJWd 3tkURYi2bjMo=", "_method"=>"PUT", "id"=>"2120", "Upload"=>"Submit Query", "fileext"=>"*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png", "controller"=>"rooms", "room"=>{"photo_uploads"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20100426-1152-12dn5rn-0>}}
  [4;36;1mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mArgumentError: redundant UTF-8 sequence: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1[0m

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (ArgumentError: redundant UTF-8 sequence: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1)  LIMIT 1):
lib/authenticated_system.rb:109:in `login_from_session'
lib/authenticated_system.rb:12:in `current_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:296:in `setup_page_titles'
lib/redis_db_logging.rb:18:in `enable_redis_logging'
lib/redis_logger.rb:43:in `redisize'
lib/redis_logger.rb:42:in `redisize'
lib/redis_db_logging.rb:11:in `enable_redis_logging'
haml (2.2.2) lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process_without_compass'
/home/crashpaddernew/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.8/lib/compass/app_integration/rails/action_controller.rb:7:in `process'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:91:in `process_request'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:206:in `main_loop'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:376:in `start_request_handler'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:334:in `handle_spawn_application'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:182:in `safe_fork'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:332:in `handle_spawn_application'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in `__send__'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in `main_loop'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:195:in `start_synchronously'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:162:in `start'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:213:in `start'
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:261:in `spawn_rails_application'
```

Does anyone know what a 'redundant UTF-8 sequence' error is, and why requests coming from the flash uploader are causing it? Or is it a problem with the JSON somehow?

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody else is frantically Googling "redundant UTF-8 sequence" (likely because you are attempting to upload an Excel document to a Rails app), let me save you some hairline.

[A fix has been implemented in the 3-2-stable branch of rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/815a9431ab61376a7e8e1bdff21f87bc557992f8#activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb), but not released yet. In order to get this goodness into your own app, simply create this file:

```
module ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding
  def self.escape(string)
    if string.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
       string = string.encode(::Encoding::UTF_8, :undef => :replace).force_encoding(::Encoding::BINARY)
    end
    json = string.gsub(escape_regex) { |s| ESCAPED_CHARS[s] }
    json = %("#{json}")
    json.force_encoding(::Encoding::UTF_8) if json.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
    json
  end
end
```

...and be sure to `require` it. You should be good to go, after that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that patch is reverted on Rails 3.2.14
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c910388587220e962682b0b9187e79b8f1641c17

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're running into this bug:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1112-redundant-utf-8-sequence-in-stringto_json

Seems to failing on your authenticate from session call, perhaps your session key has the characters mentioned in the bug report.