# ArgumentError: redundant UTF-8 sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

Hi i am unable to figure what is the actual issue. i am using rails 2.3.18 and ruby 1.8.7 
The stack trace of the error is as follows

```
  …tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  68:in `unpack'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  68:in `escape'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  63:in `gsub'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  63:in `escape'
…port-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/string.rb:   3:in `to_json'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  79:in `encode'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `__send__'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `encode'
…-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/enumerable.rb:  11:in `to_json'
…-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/enumerable.rb:  11:in `map'
…-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/enumerable.rb:  11:in `to_json'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  79:in `encode'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `__send__'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `encode'
…port-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/object.rb:   4:in `to_json'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  79:in `encode'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `__send__'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `encode'
…-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/enumerable.rb:  11:in `to_json'
…-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/enumerable.rb:  11:in `map'
…-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/enumerable.rb:  11:in `to_json'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  79:in `encode'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `__send__'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `encode'
…upport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/hash.rb:  38:in `to_json'
…s/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb:  95:in `map'
…upport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/hash.rb:  37:in `each'
…upport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/hash.rb:  37:in `map'
…upport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/hash.rb:  37:in `to_json'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  79:in `encode'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `__send__'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `encode'
…port-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/object.rb:   4:in `to_json'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  79:in `encode'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `__send__'
…tivesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:  18:in `encode'
…upport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/hash.rb:  38:in `to_json'
…s/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb:  95:in `map'
…upport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/hash.rb:  37:in `each'
…upport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/hash.rb:  37:in `map'
…upport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/json/encoders/hash.rb:  37:in `to_json'
```

I have no clue how to reproduce this error.

[Ruby Rails, jQuery, Uploadify - weird UTF-8 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713105/ruby-rails-jquery-uploadify-weird-utf-8-error) tells me how to solve this issue can anyone explain what is problem and how to reproduce this?

Comment: Looks like a fix for this was integrated into Rails v3.2 according to the other answer you linked. So upgrade.

Comment: but i want to know how to reproduce this issue...?